# ErrorException Creating default object from empty value: Trying to insert and update simultaneously

Tags: php, laravel

I am working my first Laravel 7 project and I have his code which runs well and inserts a new transaction record:

```
 public function store1(Request $request, $invoice_id)
    {
     $invoice = Invoice::find($invoice_id);
         $transaction = new Transaction();
         $transaction->added_on = Carbon\Carbon::now();
         $transaction->pay_ref = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
         $transaction->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
         $transaction->paid_amount = $request->paid_amount;
         $transaction->paid_method = 'Wallet';
         $transaction->status = 1;
         $transaction->invoice()->associate($invoice);
         $transaction->save();

         Flash::success('Transaction done successfully.');
         return redirect()->route('invoices.show', [$invoice->id]);  
}
```

Then I edited the code and added a new line to update a column in my Logged in the `users` table

```
public function store1(Request $request, $invoice_id)
    {
    $invoice = Invoice::find($invoice_id);
         $transaction = new Transaction();
         $transaction->added_on = Carbon\Carbon::now();
         $transaction->pay_ref = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
         $transaction->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
         $transaction->paid_amount = $request->paid_amount;
         $transaction->paid_method = 'Wallet';
         $transaction->status = 1;
         $transaction->invoice()->associate($invoice);
         $transaction->save();

         $user->amount = Auth::user()->amount - $transaction->paid_amount;
         $user->update();

         Flash::success('Transaction done successfully.');
         return redirect()->route('invoices.show', [$invoice->id]);

}
```

When I now try to add Transaction it throws up the error:

> ErrorException
>   Creating default object from empty value"

My plan is to update the amount attached to the logged in user by deducting the paid amount from the balance the logged in user has represented by `:amount` in he user's table as shown below:

```
$table->id();
            $table->date('added_on')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->string('station')->nullable();
            $table->float('amount', 10, 2)->nullable();
            $table->tinyinteger('status')->default(0);
            $table->integer('role_id')->default(0);
            $table->string('phone')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
```

I have also imported the User Model and Auth Component into this `TransactionController`

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and kindly show me a better way.
Additionally I want to simultaneously update the status column of the Invoice table before the redirection and flash.

Comment: You never actually create the `$user` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the user model but you have never initialized the `$user` variable.

Try this:

```
$user = user::findOrFail((Auth::id());
$user->amount = Auth::user()->amount - $transaction->paid_amount;
$user->update();
```